# How to solve <Request 400> Error in django?

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I tried to make a request from my Django project.
This is my code:

```
st_data = {"documentId": 1388,
                       "type": 1,
                       "useAsMain": True
                       }

headers2 = {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token_key,
                "Content-Type": "application/json"

            }

statement = requests.post(url_statement, headers=headers2, data=json.dumps(st_data))
```

The response of this request is **<response 400>**
And the error code is:

```
{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"00-0bbcfce14dfc2146b553c2d98c323b3d-80f72a6fe60f18
4c-00","errors":{"$":["The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Otc.Data.Objects.StatementDTO]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLi
ne: 1."]}}
```

But when I send request from Swagger UI like;

[image: swagger]

It returns **<response 200>**

Where is my mistake?

Comment: remove the `json.dumps(...)`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it gives the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

st_data needs to be a list as it can be seen in Swagger UI example request.

```
st_data = [{"documentId": 1388,
                   "type": 1,
                   "useAsMain": True
                   }]
```